# Custom Assets Library List Definition

Tags: 2013, list, list-definition

I need to create a custom list definition for "Asset Library" in SharePoint 2013. Eventually i need to add my custom content type to it. Hence the reason for the custom list definition.

The custom list definition based on the AssetLibrary cannot be created directly through VS 2010/2013, SharePoint list definition template in VS doesn’t provide option to create such a list definition.

I am NOT looking for any code (c#, js, etc) solutions, but rather XML declarative solution through VS2013.

Only reference online I could find was this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6f7fd02c-e07a-4e2e-90fc-e06e3ac135e5/list-instance-based-on-asset-library

I was able to copy schema.xml from the 15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\AssetLibrary\AssetLibrary folder and deploy my custom definition. But none of the views nor forms are coming through.

Can some one provide complete solution on how to create a custom list definition based on "Assets Libary"?

Answer (score 0):

Details on the technet article are a bit flaky.

Here are the steps to create a custom list template based on Asset Library:

1. Create a List definition from VS
2. Copy All contents from {SharePointRoot}\Template\Features\AssetLibrary\AssetLibrary at your custom List definition.
3. Select all imported files from previous step and mark those as 'ElementFile' deployment type. Probably that is the step you are missing, hence all pages are not provisioned.
4. Open elements.xml and make sure BaseType=1 and Name attribute corresponds to your list Folder.
5. Open schema.xml and make sure BaseType=1 and Url matches the Name of your list Folder.
6. Deploy and test.